# Is a sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ a maximally connected 2 dim'l smooth submanifold about canonical embedding?

Tags: differential-geometry

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> Given a distribution $\mathscr{D}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ spanned by the vector fields 
>   $$X=y\frac{\partial}{\partial z}-z\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\quad Y=z\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$$
>   find the maximal integral submanifolds of $\mathscr{D}$.

The gradient of the sphere $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=c$ is $\displaystyle 2x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+2y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+2z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$, and because $\mathscr{D}$ is perpendicular to the gradient vector at each point, it seems that spheres are part of maximal solutions. If I could show each sphere is a maximal solution, then I guess spheres would have to be the only maximal integral submanifolds of $\mathscr{D}$, because any solution that pass through some sphere will have to be contained in the sphere.(But I'm not sure)

What I thought is if some maximal solution $Y$ contains, for example, the unit sphere and contains some point $p$ not in the unit sphere, then for $Y$ to be connected, it should contain points from each spheres $\{S_{\alpha}\}$ that are concentric with the unit sphere and lie between $p$ and the unit sphere, because otherwise $Y$ will be disconnected by one of such spheres. From here, I thought that due to maximality of $Y$, $Y$ should just contain each sphere in $\{S_{\alpha}\}$ because $Y$ contains a point from each $S_{\alpha}$. But then $Y$ is not 2 dimensional, which is not the case.

However, I actually don't know if $Y$ would have to contain each $S_{\alpha}$ just because $Y$ is maximal. Also, it just seems like spheres in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ are maximally connected 2 dim'l  smooth submanifolds about canonical embedding. I don't know if this is true, but if this is true then the spheres would have to be maximal solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to remark that every connected integral submanifold is contained in a sphere. Let $N$ be a an integral submanifold, and $c(t)$ a differentiable tangent to $N$, $c'(t)={d\over {dt}}c(t)$ is an element of $T_{c(t)}N$. This implies that it is a linear combination of $X(c(t))$ and $Y(c(t))$. This implies that $c'(t)$ is orthogonal to $c(t)$. You have ${d\over{dt}}\| c(t)\|^2=2\langle c(t),c'(t)\rangle=0$. This implies that $\|c(t\|$ is constant.